# How do I know If any navigation app (e.g. Google Maps, Yandex Navigator, etc) is installed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I need to know if any of Road Navigation app is installed.
Usually I use `packageManager?.getPackageInfo(PACKAGE, 0)`. But is there a way to do the same for implict Intents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PackageManager:

```
getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

If you are running Android 11 and above, you need the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES">
```

Then you can iterate it as follows:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> currInfo = mPackageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for (ApplicationInfo tmpInf :
            currInfo) {
        PackageInfo info = 
        mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(tmpInf.packageName, 0);
        if(tmpInf.packageName.equals(PACKAGE_YOU_NEED_TO_CHECK))
           // A package you need is installed
        }
```

Comment: Can you answer how to find out if any of the Road navigation software is installed. Your  answer doesn't answer it

Comment: This gives you a list of all installed applications which you can iterate through and search for the specific package you want to check